# Sort in Ascending Order Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, view

Hi I have this model

Model item

```
class Inventory::Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :types, :class_name => "ItemType"
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Model item_type

```
class Inventory::ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item 
  attr_accessible :number
end
```

then let say in controller I want to sort types (which has class ItemType) in ascending order based on Item name. How do I do that?

For example,

- ItemType number = 1 has Item name = Table
- ItemType number = 2 has Item name = Chair
- ItemType number = 3 has Item name = Window
- ItemType number = 4 has Item name = Computer

So instead of sorting it from number, I want it sorted based on item.name(ASC) like this:

- ItemType number = 2 has Item name = Chair
- ItemType number = 4 has Item name = Computer
- ItemType number = 1 has Item name = Table
- ItemType number = 3 has Item name = Window

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick...

```
ItemType.includes( :item ).order( 'inventory_items.name DESC' )
```

Also, if you need to do this in many locations, you can accomplish the same thing by providing an `:order` parameter to your `has_many` call, instead - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many.

Answer (score 19):

To retrieve records from the database in a specific order, you can use the [`order` method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering):

```
Item.order(:name)
```

*by default this sorts ascending.*

Answer (score 2):

For making ASC (Default sorting mode) for name kind of fields (Alphabets),

```
You can use ORDER BY Clause in MySQL
```

Hence, In Rails you can simply use

```
Model.order(:field_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set default order in your Model like this:

```
default_scope order("#{self.table_name}.item_name ASC")
```

This will sort items by item_name without any change in controller

Answer (score -3):

In your query, you can use/add `ORDER BY itemType ASC`