# Two ordering parameters - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application, where I need to sort ideas on the main screen:

1. By the number of votes for an idea
2. By the descending date

This is my controller:

```
def telaPrincipal   
    @listOfIdeas = Idea.all
end
```

And this is my HTML:

```
      <% @listOfIdeas.each do |t| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= t.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%y")%></td>

  <td><%= link_to t.title, t.link_to_idea.match(/^.*:(:\/\/)/) ? t.link_to_idea : "http://#{t.link_to_idea}", :target => "_blank" %></td>

<%if (isIdeaVotedByUser t, current_user.id)%>
<td>
    <%= link_to image_tag("like-button.png", border: 0), {action: 'destroy', controller: 'votes', id: t.votes.where(:users_id => current_user.id).pluck(:id).first}, data:{confirm:"Tem certeza que deseja cancelar o seu voto?"},
 :method => :delete, class: 'like-button'%>
</td>
<%else %>
<td>
    <%= link_to image_tag("semlike-button.png", border: 0), {action: 'create', controller: 'votes' , idea_id: t.id , idea_user: t.users_id}, 
 :method => :post, class: 'like-button'%>
</td>
<% end %>


<td>
<%= t.votes.count%>
</td>
```

I was thinking of something like this: `Ideas.order ('created_at: desc'; 'votes desc')`

On the main screen, as you can see, I used `t.votes.count` to sum.

Obs.: Class Idea...

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes , :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`Votes` is a table in my DB.

I'm new to rails and I do not know how to make these queries native so to speak

My Rails is 5.1.2

Thanks!!!

Comment: particularly https://stackoverflow.com/a/31378899/525478

Comment: Ok, the date i understanded, but how make the sum of votes i don't undestanded.

Because I cannot use:
    @listOfIdeas = Idea.all.order(created_at: :desc, votes:  :desc)


At least it did not work

Comment: That will not work if `votes` is a relation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487098/order-an-activerecord-relation-object You can sort by votes by default however in the association declaration

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/16456610/525478 (i think you can do that with the new syntax, too...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to sort the record, but from my understanding of your question, you should be able to just update your controller action:

Edit: updated to calculate votes and use Rails 5 left_joins to include votes with count 0

```
def telaPrincipal
  @listOfIdeas = Idea
                   .left_joins(:votes)
                   .group(:id)
                   .select('ideas.*', 'COUNT(votes.id) vote_count')
                   .order('vote_count DESC', created_at: :desc)
end
```

Comment: @gustavo-rey Silly me, I didn't actually count the votes. This syntax should be correct, but I am actually not running Rails 5 at the moment (left_joins is introduced there). Its faster for you to try it out, but I am getting rails updated and will change the answer if I also find it not working

Comment: This or you can use AR's counter_cache field http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache